# How do I scale the text without increasing the resolution of the font?

Tags: python, text, pygame, scale, rectangles

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

run = True
scale = 3
width = 256
height = 224
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width*scale, height*scale), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
highScore = 0

textColour = (0,0,0)
font = pygame.font.Font("FreeSerif.ttf", 10)
textSurface = font.render(f"HiScore: {highScore}", True, (textColour))
textRect = textSurface.get_rect()
textRect.center = (width*scale//2, height*scale//2)


while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
    highScore += 1
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    textSurface = font.render(f"HiScore: {highScore}", True, (textColour))
    screen.blit(textSurface, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I'm making a game with a lower resolution for stylistic purposes, and I have a system for multiplying everything with the scale variable.
How do I scale the text without increasing the resolution of the font?

I've tried setting the textRect.w and textRect.h manually, I've tried pygame.transform.scale on multiple things and I've tried the inflate method. All expecting the text to scale, but no luck.

Comment: You can scale the rendered surface, but this will result in pixelated or blurred text. So don't do it. Use different font objects of different text size for different scale. This the only option to get a good quality.

Comment: Pygame.transform.scale would work for this and it might not look bad if you scale up by an integer amount. You didn’t show code for transform.scale, perhaps you’re not using the output of that function? Remember that transform.scale returns a new scaled surface rather than changing the scale of the passed argument.

Comment: @Rabbid76, Using a font of a bigger text size will make the text another resolution from the rest of the game.

Comment: @Starbuck5, where am i supposed to use pygame.transform.scale? I've tried ´screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(text, textRect), (textRect.x*scale, textRect.y*scale))´
I've tried
´text = pygame.transform.scale(text, (text.x*scale, text.y*scale))´

Comment: @sihea You can create more than 1 font object.

Comment: @sihea Unless you’ve changed the size of textrect, you’re just scaling it to the same size it already was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to decide on the approach you'd prefer, you can iterate through a few options and see what they look like.

Here's an example that loops through some font sizes and scaling factors:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

run = True
scale = 3
width = 256
height = 224
# screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width*scale, height*scale), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width * scale, height * scale))
high_score= 0

text_colour = (0, 0, 0)
fonts = []
font_sizes = 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 24, 30, 36
for size in font_sizes:
    # font = pygame.font.Font("FreeSerif.ttf", size)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size) 
    fonts.append(font)

font_scales = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
grid_width = width * scale // len(font_scales)
grid_height = height * scale // len(font_sizes)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    high_score+= 1
    screen.fill("red")
    for y, font in enumerate(fonts):
        for x, f_scale in enumerate(font_scales):
            # msg = f"{font_sizes[y]} x {f_scale:2} : {high_score}"
            msg = f"{font_sizes[y]} x {f_scale:2}"
            text_surface = font.render(msg, True, (text_colour))
            text_surface = pygame.transform.scale_by(text_surface, f_scale)
            text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
            text_rect.left = grid_width * x + 10
            text_rect.top = grid_height * y + 10
            screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

The larger text sizes and scales overlap and the spacing could be improved, but it should be enough for you to compare and build upon.

[image: Unintended Zalgo]

I also changed some variable names to match the Python Style Guide ([PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)).

Comment: I'm getting the error that "'pygame.transform' has no attribute 'scale_by'"

Comment: @sihea [`transform.scale_by(...)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale_by) was introduced in PyGame **2.1.3**. If you have an earlier version and don't want to upgrade you can use [`transform.scale(...)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) with an explicit size; i.e., `x = width * scaling_factor`, etc. Let us know if you're not able to get it working.

Comment: Raspi's built in pygame version was 1.9.x, and the latest supported non-dev version was 2.1.2, but after updating the OS, python and then downloading pygame version 2.1.3.dev8, I've run into the problem that fullscreen has started to bug out. The scaling works now, though, so that's cool.